# ¿Cómo asignar la fecha en una única celda VBA mientras ingreso datos en otra?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo esto para que me aparezca la fecha actual mientras ingreso cualquier valor en la celda U12 al hacer esto quiero que en la celda V12 me aparezca la fecha actual del sistema pero no me lo hace mi código, desconozco la sintaxis.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "U12" Then
    Target.Address = "V12" = Now
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cuestiones a considerar.

`Target.Address` devuelve una referencia absoluta de fila y columna, algo así `$U$12`, por lo cual no coincidirá con `U12`.
Se soluciona poniendo como falsos sus dos primeros argumentos, por lo que el código queda así: `If Target.Address(False, False) = "U12" Then`, también funciona de este modo: `If Target.Address = "$U$12" Then`

`Target.Address` devuelve una referencia, por lo que no le puede hacer una asignación, para hacer referencia a un rango y darle valor al mismo, se puede usar `Target.Range`, algo como esto: `Target.Range("V12") = Now`

`Now` devuelve fecha y hora, por lo que si solo necesitas la fecha, es necesario usar `Date` en su lugar.

Tomando en cuanta los detalles anteriores, el siguiente código puede ser de ayuda.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "U12" Then
        Target.Range("V12") = Date
    End If
End Sub
```